# Are Mootools More and Mootools Core are same or Different?

Tags: mootools

I am very new to Mootools but have good experience in jQuery.
Recently i came to know that Mootools is another excellent choice. But bit confused when opened the mootools site.

What is the difference between Mootools Core and Mootools More?

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mootools-core is the actual framework. mootools-more is otherwise known as the officially supported plugins that you can build (it's modular so you can choose which parts of more you want) to complement mootools-core.

most notably, parts of -more you may want are:

- Element.delegate - provides event delegation via `click:relay(selector)`
- Request.JSONP

and whatever takes your fancy.